# pregmatch Multiple source

Tags: php, preg-match

How do I exactly match multiple instances of img tags? I read up a few tutorials on preg_match yet never really quite understand.

I have this as my base:

```
<img src="http://example.com/1.png" alt="Example" />

<img class="Class" src="http://example.com/2.jpg" alt="Example 2" />
```

And I did up a small like regex:

```
<img (src="|class="Class" src=")http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png)" alt="
```

After this, I'm stuck. How do I continue to match all till the end of the both strings?

I found out about the array part on PHP website itself:

```
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i',
    "http://www.php.net/index.html", $matches);
$host = $matches[1];
```

Using my code, how do I get the image URL, and the alt tag?

Thanks!

Comment: to match `src` attribute from multiple img tags, use [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original question, use `preg_match_all()` function to get all the matches.

For the second question ("Using my code, how do I get the image URL, and the alt tag?"), basically your regex is correct. However, I would suggest to get the whole `<img>` tag first, then do another `preg_match()` to get the `href` and `alt` attributes, since their order may vary.

```
$html = "<img src='test.jpg' alt='aaaaaaaaaaa!'>  adfa <img src='test2.jpg' alt='aaaaaaaaaaa2'>  ";

$pattern = '/<img\s[^>]*>/';
$count = preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

echo "Found: " . $count . "\n";
if ($count > 0) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $img = $match[0];
        echo "img: " . $img . "\n";
        if (preg_match("/src=['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]/", $img, $val)) {  # UPDATE: use () to catch the content of src
            $src = $val[1];      # UPDATE: get the part in ()
        }
        if (preg_match("/alt=['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]/", $img, $val)) {   # UPDATE
            $alt = $val[1];      # UPDATE
        }

        echo "src = " . $src . ", alt = " . $alt . "\n";
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Answer to your comment.
Sure. Just use a group to catch the part after `src=`.
I updated the source above and commented with "UPDATE".

Comment: Thanks! This works! However, the results are still consist of the text `src="`. Is it possible to remove them in preg_match itself? Or do I have to manually remove them using `str_replace` or something? Because I've seen before codes that get the img links straight from preg_match. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not `DOMDocument`? You can get all attributes no matter how the images are written:

```
$string = '<img class="Class" src="http://example.com/2.jpg" alt="Example 2" />';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = '//img';
$elements = $xpath->query($query);

$attributes = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($elements as $one){
    foreach($one->attributes as $att){
        $attributes[$i][$att->nodeName] = $att->nodeValue;
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r($attributes);

/*Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [class] => Class
            [src] => http://example.com/2.jpg
            [alt] => Example 2
        )

)*/
```

Comment: Thanks for this! However, I'm not really good at `DomDocument`, so I guess I'll just stick to the normal. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Regex is not normal for HTML. :)